# Box creation is making the physics pause

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

This is the code to create a box, this code is called when you click the down key. I would like help making a box that spawns at the bottom of my screen and moves across the page

```
var boxes

function preload() {
  this.load.image('box', 'assets/box.png');
}
function create() {
  this.w = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W)
  this.a = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A)
  this.s = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S)
  this.d = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D)
  box = this.physics.add.group();
  boxes = box.create(0, 900, 'box').setScale(0.1);
  boxes.body.setAllowGravity(false);
  boxes.setVelocityX(200)
  this.physics.add.collider(player, boxes);
}
function update() {
  let cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  if (this.s.isDown) {
    if (wait = 1) {
      createBox()
    }
  }
}
function createBox() {
  box = this.physics.add.group();
  boxes = box.create(0, 900, 'box').setScale(0.1);
  boxes.body.setAllowGravity(false);
  boxes.setVelocityX(200)
  this.physics.add.collider(player, boxes);
  this.time.delayedCall(1000, delayer, null, this);
}
```

I also create the box once in the create function and it works

I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Comment: I answered your question, if you need more help please post the code you use for the _click down key._

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that in your *down* event function, you didn't passt the scene as context. I'm to sure which method you are using, but here an example what I mean:

- If you are using the `input.keyboard.on` way ([here the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyboardPlugin.html)):

  ```
  this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-DOWN', function (event) {
      // ...
  }, this); // <- finall *this*  is very important
  ```

> the final `this` is the scene, that you need to pass to the keyboard event-callback. So that the `this` in your function `createBox` points to the `scene`and not to the browser `window`;

Comment: this did not work becuase i use the
  this.w = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W)
  this.a = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A)
  this.s = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S)
  this.d = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D)

Comment: i created a new question with all of my code under the label *creating a box that moves across the screen in phaser 3*, 

thanks for the help anyways

Comment: thanks for the information, I will check, it out. _btw.: you can update your questions, you don't need to create a new question just to add code or post code in the comment sections_

Comment: ya i realised that after i posted the new question and was to afraid to delete it after the warning message